# writing and reading from a file in c

Tags: c, function, file, scanf, fopen

What I'm trying to do is to write 2 functions :
 a function that writes in a file and a function that reads the same file…
I face two problems :
1-when I execute the two function at the same time :
 the first function work almost correctly but it didn’t return 1 ; and the second function read my file correctly but it give me after that infinite series of 0s.
2-when I execute only the second function(reading) , it give me infinite series of 0s and it didn’t read what I have inside the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 struct Product
    {
        int Code;
        char Name[30];
        float Price;

    };
    struct Product p[15];

int SaveProduct(int n) // n number of product
{
    int i;
     FILE *f;
     if((f=fopen("save.txt","w"))==NULL)

     {
         return 0;
     }
     else{
     fprintf(f,"Code\tName\tPrice\n");


     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
        printf("enter Code,Name,Price\n");
      scanf("%d %s %f",&p[i].Code, p[i].Name,&p[i].Price);
      fprintf(f,"%d \t %s\t %.2f\n",p[i].Code, p[i].Name,p[i].Price);
     }
     fclose(f);
        return 1;
     }
}
void displayProduct()
    {

        FILE *f;
        if ( (f=fopen("save.txt","r"))==NULL )
        {
            printf("error");
        }
        else
        {int i=0;
            printf("Code\tName\tPrice\n");
           while(fscanf(f,"%d %s %f",&p[i].Code,p[i].Name,&p[i].Price) != EOF)

             {

                printf("%d\t %s\t %.2f\n",p[i].Code,p[i].Name,p[i].Price);
                i++;
                }

            fclose(f);
        }

    }





int main()

{

    SaveProduct(3);  //3 number of product
      displayProduct();


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the line and run again :)

```
fprintf(f,"Code\tName\tPrice\n");
```

The above line was causing the output to the save.txt file like below-

```
Code Name Price    // line 1
123  aa   10       // line 2
456  bb   20       // line 3
789  cc   30       // line 4
```

When the program was reading the file with

```
fscanf(f,"%d %s %f",&p[i].Code,p[i].Name,&p[i].Price)
```

it was getting wrong input for **line 1**. That's why the above code from **SaveProduct** function should be removed so that **line 1** doesn't get writen in the file.

Comment: thanks a lot... but why SaveProduct() didn't return 1 and what's wrong with this line fprintf(f,"Code\tName\tPrice\n");

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer to your question 2) why the second function, i.e. `displayProduct`, it give me infinite series of 0s...?

There are at least two issues:

a) Why it got 0?

As @Abdullah Al Masud Tushar already answered, the first line of the file `save.txt` being read is `Code<TAB>Name<TAB>Price`, while the format string for `fscanf` is `"%d %s %f"`. The `%d` is expecting:

> Any number of decimal digits (0-9), optionally preceded by a sign (+ or -).

But 'C' is met, then `fscanf` stops without filling any item and returns, leaving items unchanged. And, your struct array `p` is global variable and is initialized as all-zeroes.

b) Why infinite?
`fscanf` returns number of items being successfully filled normally; It returns EOF only when error happens or the end-of-file is reached before any data could be successfully read.

In your case, due to reason of issue a), zero is returned and the condition `fscanf(...) != EOF` is always true.

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file.
>
> If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror). ***And, if either happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned***.

Again, there are some additional issues of `fscanf`:

c) In the file, `'\t'` is used as field delimiter (when writing) but in format string of `fscanf` blank space (`' '`) is used, hence blank space is expected.

d) `%s` expects any number of non-whitespace characters, stopping at the first whitespace character found. If the "name" input contains whitespace, it cannot be filled correctly, and what's more will confuse the later `%f`.

See the manual of `fscanf` at
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/
or
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html